# Aggregation using 'by' and secondary indicies in data table

Tags: r, data.table

Looking through the 4th data.table vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-secondary-indices-and-auto-indexing.html) (secondary indices and auto indexing) it looks like example 2f. returns the wrong month label.

```
flights <- read.csv(url("https://github.com/arunsrinivasan/flights/wiki/NYCflights14/flights14.csv"))
```

The example gives:

```
> head(flights["JFK", max(dep_delay), keyby = month, on = "origin"])

   month   V1
1:     1  881
2:     1 1014
3:     1  920
4:     1 1241
5:     1  853
6:     1  798
```

But replicating this without using secondary indices gives:

```
> head(flights[origin == "JFK", max(dep_delay), keyby = month])

   month   V1
1:     1  881
2:     2 1014
3:     3  920
4:     4 1241
5:     5  853
6:     6  798
```

The error can be seen by looking for the row with dep_delay == 1014

```
> flights[month =="1" & dep_delay == 1014]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 17 cols: year,month,day,dep_time,dep_delay,arr_time...


> flights[month =="2" & dep_delay == 1014]
year month day dep_time dep_delay arr_time arr_delay cancelled carrier tailnum flight origin dest air_time distance hour min
1: 2014     2  21      844      1014     1151      1007         0      DL  N983DL   2459    JFK  MCO      139      944    8  44
```

Is this an error in the example code, or a data.table flaw?

Comment: Which version of `data.table`? `head(flights["JFK", max(dep_delay), keyby = month, on = "origin"])` gives me `month   V1
1:     1  881
2:     2 1014 ...` on version 1.10.0 and `month   V1
1:     1  881
2:     1 1014 ...` on version 1.10.4.3

Comment: Currently using:

> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.10.4.2’